# Downloading excel file from S3 is not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I'm creating a web application in Flask.
And I'm trying to make the page where user can download excel file which is uploaded in S3 bucket.

But the code doesn't work and I get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 41-43: ordinal not in range(256)

Below is the code I'm using:

```py
# download file from s3
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
file = my_bucket.Object(file_name).get()

try:
    return Response(
        file['Body'].read(),
        mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel',
        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename={}".format(file_name)}
    )
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred method would be to provide a **URL to the object** that they can use to download directly from Amazon S3. This also has the benefit of offloading traffic from your app server.

If the object is private, then you can generate a [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a URL that provides time-limited access to a private object.